# Visual Studio Debug Console displaying extra information that makes reading information hard

Tags: debugging

I'm getting all this bracketed information that makes reading the VS 2019 debug output hard.  I just want the text:

Starting Host...
Information IdentityServer4 Startup
Starting IdentityServer4 Startup.... ectc, ect.

Below is an example of the kind of output I'm getting in the debug console.  How do I clean this up where I just have the meaningful text?

__________________________________________ Output __________________________________

←[38;5;0253m[←[0m←[38;5;0246m17:05:05←[0m←[38;5;0253m ←[0m←[37;1mInformation←[0m←[38;5;0253m] ←[0m
←[38;5;0253mStarting host...←[0m

←[38;5;0253m[←[0m←[38;5;0246m17:05:07←[0m←[38;5;0253m ←[0m←[37;1mInformation←[0m←[38;5;0253m] ←[0m←[38;5;0246mIdentityServer4.Startup←[0m
←[38;5;0253mStarting IdentityServer4 version ←[0m←[38;5;0216m4.0.0+1acafade44176bf817412aa4309d5dff6587a741←[0m

←[38;5;0253m[←[0m←[38;5;0246m17:05:07←[0m←[38;5;0253m ←[0m←[37;1mInformation←[0m←[38;5;0253m] ←[0m←[38;5;0246mIdentityServer4.Startup←[0m
←[38;5;0253mYou are using the in-memory version of the persisted grant store. This will store consent decisions, authorization codes, refresh and refer
ns in memory only. If you are using any of those features in production, you want to switch to a different store implementation.←[0m

←[38;5;0253m[←[0m←[38;5;0246m17:05:07←[0m←[38;5;0253m ←[0m←[37;1mInformation←[0m←[38;5;0253m] ←[0m←[38;5;0246mIdentityServer4.Startup←[0m
←[38;5;0253mUsing the default authentication scheme ←[0m←[38;5;0216midsrv←[0m←[38;5;0253m for IdentityServer←[0m

←[38;5;0253m[←[0m←[38;5;0246m17:05:07←[0m←[38;5;0253m ←[0m←[37mDebug←[0m←[38;5;0253m] ←[0m←[38;5;0246mIdentityServer4.Startup←[0m
←[38;5;0253mUsing ←[0m←[38;5;0216midsrv←[0m←[38;5;0253m as default ASP.NET Core scheme for authentication←[0m